# Вычисление функции разложением в ряд

Tags: c, алгоритм, c++

Вычислить и вывести на экран в виде таблицы, значения функции, заданной с помощью ряда Тейлора, на интервале от Xнач до Xкон с шагом dx с точностью ε. Таблицу обеспечить заголовком и шапкой. Каждая строка таблицы должна содержать значение аргумента, значение функции и количество суммированных членов ряда.
Можете пожалуйста помочь в составлении алгоритма для решения задачи. К сожалению, суть задачи не понятна.
[image: Формула]

Comment: @VladBbnko, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.
Да, и переведите на русский, в крайнем случае есть же translate.google.com.

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, это вычислительная математика.

1. Сначала вы берёте текущее значение как Xнач.(Что логично).
2. И пока текущее значение <=Xкон выполняете действия, описанные ниже, прибавляя к текущему значению шаг, после выполнения действия.
3. У нас есть X, Ряд (Здесь - сумма результатов), Точность, Шаг.

> - Выполняете действия ниже, пока результат итерации не станет <
>   Точности.
> - Зная текущий элемент(X), и шаг(n), получаем результат по формуле общего
>   члена.
> - Прибавляем его к сумме, шаг увеличиваем на 1.

Answer (score 0):

Берёшь Xнач и подставляешь в первый член ряда Тейлора, вычисляешь его, увеличиваешь общую сумму ряда для Xнач на удвоенное произведение посчитанного члена ряда, увеличиваешь счётчик посчитанных членов ряда на 1, сравниваешь с точностью. Если точность меньше эпсилон - прекращаешь (выводишь X, сумму ряда для X и кол-во посчитанных членов ряда) и переходишь к другому Х, иначе следующий член ряда. После вывода сумма и счётчик обнуляются. Как то так.